# How should I deal with a break; statement after a return statement in a javascript switch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

I have the following:

```
 switch (entity) {
    case "Topic":
        return {
            pk: "0006000",
            param: "?pk=0006000",
            table: "Content",
            success: true
        };
        break;
```

This is repeated any times with different entities. All are coded in the same way with a return statement and then a break.

When I run jslint it complains saying "break after return in case".  Is there a different way I should be coding this?

Comment: I don't think you need a `break;` statement since you're already returning if the switch matches that condition. You could use a `default:` if you want to handle other conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The break statement in this case would never hit as the values are being returned even before that..

You can safely remove the break;

But I feel returning it after storing it in a variable is a good practice

```
var obj = {};
 switch (entity) {
    case "Topic":
       obj= {
            pk: "0006000",
            param: "?pk=0006000",
            table: "Content",
            success: true
        };
        break;
   }
   return obj;
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to using {} instead of just var obj;  ?

Comment: Just to make sure undefined is not returned if it does not hit any of the case statements

Comment: You should do that with a default statement (i.e default: obj = {}), not by initiating the object at the start.

Comment: I agree with you , but instead of declaring var obj; it's a good practice to initialize a value prior to using it..

Answer (score 1):

> *" Is there a different way I should be coding this?"*

Yes, remove the `break`. It's useless right there since the function has already returned.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `break` after `return`, `return` will cause the function exist immediately, any code after `return` won't be executed.

Any other way? You could use an object to keep the relation.

```
var map = {
  'Topic' : {
            pk: "0006000",
            param: "?pk=0006000",
            table: "Content",
            success: true
   },
   // ...
};

return map[entity];
```

Comment: Thanks for you very good suggestion. However unfortunately I have a problem with some other case statements as they have some logic inside and return one thing or another :-(

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the break, but I would argue that returning from within a switch statement is not good practice.  Set a variable and return it after the switch.

Comment: xdazz made a suggestion. Would that be your way also? I am interested to explore how I could best return an object. Thank you.

Comment: I make the suggestion because you might have different cases which return different objects, and it just seems to make sense in this situation to do logic, then return once.  Before your switch, declare a return object (var retObj = {};).  Also, if I had to guess the JS runtime sets aside memory for a switch statment which gets freed by a break;  I could see a misplaced return; causing a memory leak... possibly??